# Set setCachePeriod for static resources in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot, and the `/static` is served as static resources like js and css, so far so good, while I want to set the cache header of these files, so I tried this:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(24 * 3600 * 365); 
    }
}
```

However after that, the application can not serve anything from the `/static` folder.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, it's better to use `spring.resources.cache-period` property to set the cache period of default Boot *Resource Handler*. So add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.resources.cache-period = 31536000
```

And delete the `BaseMvcConfig` config file.

Comment: With Spring default configurations, if you save your file in `classpath:/static/all.css`, you can access it through `http://localhost:8080/all.css`. If you're using that Java Config, you should send your request to `http://localhost:8080/static/all.css`.

Comment: `spring.resources.cache-period` is deprecated in favour of `spring.resources.cache.period`

Comment: spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age worked for me

Comment: `spring.resources.cache-period` and `spring.resources.cache.period` is 
deprecated. You should use: `spring.web.resources.cache.period`

Answer (score 8):

Since `spring.resources.cache-period` is deprecated, you may want to use the newer `spring.web.resources.cache.period` instead, which takes either seconds (as before), or a `Duration` specification like this:

```
spring.web.resources.cache.period = P30D
```

See [Duration#parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) JavaDoc for reference.

Comment: `spring.resources.cache.period` is 
deprecated. Now you should use: `spring.web.resources.cache.period`

Comment: Funny how my _update post_ became outdated itself. However, I will just happily update my update post. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use spring security for controllers and setup cache for static content then you might want to configure exceptions in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and set cache period in application.properties:

```
@Override 
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception { 
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**");
} 

#1 week cache
spring.resources.cache-period = 604800
```

Comment: In my particular setup (using Spring Boot 2.6.4) it doesn't seem to matter whether or not you add the `web.ignoring()` call.  The cache period (set using the newer `spring.web.resources.cache.period`) seems to control all of the static resources whether spring security thinks it is ignoring them or not.