# Cache static files by content type in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, http-headers, content-type

I'm trying to set up caching headers on specific static file type in Spring Boot.
In directory src/main/resources/static there are few subdirectories with different file types:

```
src/main/resources/static/font   --> *.otf
src/main/resources/static/lib    --> *.js
src/main/resources/static/images --> *.png, *.jpg
```

Is there a way to put cache headers by file type inside Spring configuration?

```
*.otf 365 days
*.png 30 days
*.jpg 7 days
```

Spring version is 5.2.3 and Spring Boot 2.2.4 - is there a chance that Spring Boot deals with it and makes it not work?

Tried with

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    final CacheControl oneYearPublic =
        CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic();
    // it does not "work" with "/static/fonts/"
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/fonts/{filename:\\w+\\.otf}")
        .setCacheControl(oneYearPublic);
}
```

but I get weird results. When checking with Network tab of DevTools I get these headers:

```
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
```

But when I go to the URL directly, I get 404

```
http://localhost/fonts/1952RHEINMETALL.otf
```

Without any configuration I get "no-store" Cache-Control header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to have a working solution for this problem. Check the GitHub repo https://github.com/alexsomai/cache-static-assets.

This is an example of config that should work:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(registry);

        // could use either '/**/images/{filename:\w+\.png}' or '/**/images/*.png'
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/images/{filename:\\w+\\.png}")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/images/*.jpg")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.DAYS));

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/lib/*.js")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(3, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

You could easily adjust it for your needs, based on file type and cache duration.

As key takeaways, make sure to **add** the `addResourceLocations` function (without this one, you get 404). Plus, if you are using Spring Boot, you **don't need** the `@EnableWebMvc`, as it was initially posted in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216168/6908551.

Comment: Previously tried with resource handlers but got weird results. Now I updated original question to let you see those results. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The 404 tells me that you have a different kind of issue, when accessing `/fonts/1952RHEINMETALL.otf`. What if you try to access `/static/font/1952RHEINMETALL.otf`, or `/font/1952RHEINMETALL.otf` (without s)? Are you sure that you are mapping correctly the URLs to your static resources?

Comment: 404 is returned only when resource handlers are added. If I remove resource handlers, everything is accessible. Tried now the one you proposed but still 404.

Comment: The URL is https://vegsh.com - you can watch the traffic. Then it goes more weird because I have no resource handlers deployed but Cache Control says "private".

Comment: And I am aware of non-SSL protocol on my local host and SSL protocol on my server and I'm taking it into account when watching network traffic - meaning I don't make mistake with protocol to ask for SSL version on localhost and vice versa.

Comment: I've managed to create a working solution for this use-case :) Check the GitHub repo https://github.com/alexsomai/cache-static-assets (I'll also update my answer with the correct version). It seems that the `addResourceLocations` was missing from the initial example.

Comment: @horvoje did you have time to test the last update of my suggested changes? I'm really curious if it works in your case.

Comment: Yes, your project works when I import it into the same IDE and sets expire dates as expected. But applying those resource handlers to my project - it won't work. Which tells me I have some misconfiguration or some dependency issues.

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that the configuration doesn't work in your project.

Comment: Now I can confirm it works when /**/ is added as a prefix to addResourceHandler() parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record for all those who will read this in the future - beware of your own hacks that handle URL mappings: I wanted to have favicon mapped to the root of my project but to have files inside resource directories; to have that I had to create SimpleUrlMapping bean and ResourceHttpRequestHandler. Headers should be handled additionally inside ResourceHttpRequestHandler.