# Enable Http Cache in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-caching

From my client I'm querying some enums from the server. Now, I would like to cache these enums in the client as soon as they have been queried once on the server.

I tried to set `Cache-Control` as follows:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "enums/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getEnums( @PathVariable("name") String name, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600");
    return myservice.findAllEnums(name);
}
```

The response header seems to be correctly set with `Cache-control: max-age=3600`. I also disabled all http headers in my security config as follows:

```
@Override 
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
http.headers().cacheControl().disable(); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the response is not cached in the browser. As soon as I'm querying the resource, the query is going to the server again.

Meanwhile, I removed Spring Security completly, but it still does not work.
What I did not understand correctly? What else do I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I noticed that it was working with IE, but not with Chrome. The problem with Chrome is that it sets `Cache-control: max-age=0` on the request's header if you're refrehsing the page. This obviously prevents the data from being cached. I then created a simple html using a hyperlink to my application and refresehing it via this link. Thus, the cache worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if there is any restiction made as no-cache HTTP headers are set by Spring Security. 
you can get more relevant  information here : [How to enable HTTP response caching in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164014/how-to-enable-http-response-caching-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Meanwhile, I compeltly switched off Spring Security ,but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

about the chrome behavior : [Chrome back button doesn't respect the cache-control:no-cache header](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516846)