# How do I configure cache-control for webjars in spring boot

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cache-control

I've seen a couple of existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179151/206466) but when I add the following all webjars start returning 404s. How can I configure cache control for all of my webjars?

```
@Configuration
public class HttpCacheControlConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").setCachePeriod( 3600 * 24 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't configured any resource locations for the handler. You need something like this:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
        .setCachePeriod(3600 * 24);
```

Alternatively, if you're happy for all of your static resources to have the same cache period then you don't need a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as you can just configure it with a property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.resources.cache-period = 86400
```

Comment: hey thanks, what happens if I set the `cache-period` and configure this? say I want a sane default for most statics but something different for webjars? basically I haven't cache busted my own static resources yet, but the web jars are by virtue of having versions listed in them.

Comment: If you configure both, web jars resources will have the cache period configured by your adapter. All other static resources will have the cache period configured in application.properties.

Comment: turns out I have to do `.setCacheControl( CacheControl.maxAge( 30, TimeUnit.DAYS ).cachePublic() );` without public cloudfront is opting to not cache (though not sure why it has decided it's ok to cache my non static controller response... I don't suppose there's a magic properties setting for 'public'?
`

Comment: There isn't. The properties are only for what's available on `ResourceHandlerRegistration` directly

Comment: The new Spring Boot config property is now `spring.web.resources.cache.period = 1d`