# Spring boot cache results

Tags: spring-boot

I have several read-only resources in my Controller. I want to in-memory cache them, I'm not clear how to do it in Spring Boot.
What I've done:

- annotated main Application with `@EnableCaching`
- annotated a resource with `@Cacheable`

---

```
@Cacheable
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/graph", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Map<String, String>> graph() {
    return Repository.graph();
}
```

What am I missing?
Since it's a read-only resource I guess I don't neet `@CachePut` am I right?

Obiouvsly I added `spring-boot-starter-cache` ad dependency in maven

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164014/how-to-enable-http-response-caching-in-spring-boot#24179151

Comment: are you sure a 2014 answer is still valid? Just asking :)

Comment: Do you have the right dependencies for caching?!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan yes I added the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to enable the Cache. For example i am using Google GuavaCacheManager for this purpose.

1. Add dependency and Enable the caching by using annotation on Application class.

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>18.0</version>
   </dependency>

   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableCaching
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   }
   ```
2. Expose the GuavaCacheManager as a bean in your Application class.

   ```
   @Bean
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
   GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
   // Cache expires every day
   cacheManager.setCacheBuilder(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(1, 
   TimeUnit.DAYS).expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)); 
   cacheManager.setCacheNames(Arrays.asList("findUser"));
   return cacheManager;
   }
   ```
3. Mark the method as Cacheable so all the calls to this method first try to find the entry in Cache if not found then actually calls the method

   ```
   @Override
   @Cacheable("findUser")
   public User findUser(String username) {
   // biz logic to find the user and return the object
   return user;
   }
   ```