# Test static content with MockMVC in Spring Boot with Slice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing, spring-web, mockmvc

I'm trying to figure out a way to test with MockMVC the serving of content using a WebSlice that only autoconfigs `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler` (and not controllers)

I've tried something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(
    controllers = {}
)
public class StaticAssetsMVCTest {
```

but {} is the default and it looks for all controllers. Is there a way to exclude all controllers but keep the other basic spring-web things my app has so that i can test just the static assets slices?

Answer (score 0):

What about testing static content against a **full blown server**?

Here is a [sample application](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test) to show what I'm talking about.

The entry point for such tests is a [**`@LeanWebTest`**](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/leanwebtest/lean/LeanWebTest.java) annotation:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {
    MvcConfig.class,
    WebSecurityConfig.class
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LeanWebTest {
}
```

`@LeanWebTest` is a `@SpringBootTest` using a fully configured server at random port.

It specifies the following `@Configuration` classes:

- [`MvcConfig`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/leanwebtest/web/config/MvcConfig.java) - in the sample project it is empty. But it might impact the way the server serves static content
- [`WebSecurityConfig`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/leanwebtest/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)

Spring Security [overrides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control) `Cache-Control` headers.  Probably it is not what we might want especially with static resources.

*See also: [How to enable HTTP response caching in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179151/6486622)*

`@LeanWebTest` **does not use any `@Bean`s** from the application except of specified configuration classes. (No `@Controllers` created)

I see the following aspects applicable to `@LeanWebTest`s:

- `robots.txt` file
- `javax.servlet.Filter`s
- static resources **compression**
- static resources **caching**
- etc..

The sample application has some tests:

- [`RobotsTxtTest`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/leanwebtest/web/RobotsTxtTest.java) - testing the `robots.txt` file using [RobotsTxt](https://github.com/pandzel/RobotsTxt) library
- [`StaticContentTest`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/leanwebtest/web/StaticContentTest.java) checks that static content is correctly served. Also tests that `Cache-Control` headers are set as it was specified by `application.properties`
- [`TomcatRemoteIpHeaderTest`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/leanwebtest/web/TomcatRemoteIpHeaderTest.java) - tests whether tomcat correctly applies configured [`remote-ip-header`](https://github.com/cac03/lean-web-test/blob/0041ebc90ef52503225dd4e0470ff0d41e8bb052/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1) property

---

*Please note that the project is a rough demonstration of the concept*