# How do I add Cache-Control with no-cache and no-store header in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cache-control

I have Spring Boot 3.0.4 application and I have tried many things to add Cache-Control with no-store but either nothing happens or it says that headers or something is both enabled and disabled and gives me error. I have tried the following method but it doesn't show me Cache-Control headers in the response.

```java
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {

    private final List<String> protectedPaths = List.of(
            "/users/*/**",
            "/api/**",
            "/admin/**",
    );

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers(headers -> headers.defaultsDisabled().disable()) // <-- I have added this line without help
                .csrf().disable()
                .securityMatcher(protectedPaths.toArray(new String[0]))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt(customizer -> customizer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new UserAuthenticationTokenConverter()));
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi dear @ilhan please add the exact error (ideally stack trace) to your question

Comment: @TamasCsizmadia the class above does not produce error.

Comment: gotcha! So you mentioned "it says that headers or something is both enabled and disabled and gives me error" -- I just wanted to know more about your error. Any detail can be helpful

Comment: Maybe this thread is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164014/how-to-enable-http-response-caching-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LogRequestHandler implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseCacheWrapperObject = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, responseCacheWrapperObject);
        responseCacheWrapperObject.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
        responseCacheWrapperObject.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}
```